# How to remove class unchecked Checkbox in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I using one JavaScript it work like this

on Click First input:Checkbox it's Disable All Other input:Checkbox and It Add Class to Other input:checkbox's LI

Issue it I not able to remove class one unchecked the First input:checkbox

On Check First:Checkbox result disable other checkbox successfully and also add class to other LI

Also on UnCheck First:Checkbox Result Enable other checkbox  But not Remove Class from LI

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.First:checkbox').click(function() {
   var $checkbox = $(this), checked = $checkbox.is(':checked');
   $checkbox.closest('#input_1_106').find(':checkbox').prop('disabled', checked);
   $('#tree li').not('.FirstLi').addClass('xxxxxxxxx');   

   $checkbox.prop('disabled', false);
});
});
```

I want on UnCheck First:Checkbox Remove Class from Other LI

Comment: It would be a good idea if you include the relevant HTML code.

Comment: And it would be even better idea if you would sort out expected result definition like 'when I do `x` I'm supposed to get `y` and `z`'. Or the question body seems too vague and messy to me only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed out the conditional statement before adding class. Below should work for you.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.First:checkbox').click(function() {
        var $checkbox = $(this), checked = $checkbox.is(':checked');
        $checkbox.closest('#input_1_106').find(':checkbox').prop('disabled', checked);
        if(checked){
            $('#tree li').not('.FirstLi').addClass('xxxxxxxxx');
        }else{
            $('#tree li').not('.FirstLi').removeClass('xxxxxxxxx');
        }  
        $checkbox.prop('disabled', false);
    });
});
```